# How to handle a login network call from an Activity in Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, intentservice

How should one handle a network call to login when a user enters their username and password and clicks "login" in an activity?

Using an AsyncTask is not a good idea for various reasons discussed elsewhere (such as, when you rotate the device, the AsyncTask is destroyed).

The option I was considering is using launching an IntentService from the activity. You pass the username and password to that IntentService and in OnHandleIntent() you do your network call. After the network call is done, you broadcast either success or fail data. That same LoginActivity has a BroadcastReceiver that picks up the broadcast and you can handle the rest of the UI.

The disadvantage of using an IntentService though is if the activity is destroyed or the app is closed, the IntentService will still continue to run until it is done.

Is there a better 2016 way to do this?

Comment: Try not to think of it as login, but as a more general async network problem. If you don't want to use a library, intentservice is the best way to handle this, and let any receivers handle the logic (if anyone is indeed listening as you mentioned)

Answer (score 0):

How about having the asynctask inside a fragment and set retain instance. It should retain asynctask as well.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use any third party lib. Such as
Volley:

http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

AQuery:

https://code.google.com/p/android-query/